# 2016 Community Moderator Election

Tags: discussion, moderators, election

The 2016 Community Moderator Election is now underway!

Community moderator elections have three phases:

1. Nomination phase
2. Primary phase
3. Election phase

Most elections take between two and three weeks, but this depends on how many candidates there are.

Please visit the official election page at

https://scifi.stackexchange.com/election

for more detail, and to participate!

If you have general questions about the election process, or questions for moderator candidates, feel free to ask them here on meta -- just make sure your questions are tagged [election](/questions/tagged/election).

Comment: I nominate @Slytherincess.

Comment: I'm also tempted to nominate myself, just for the sheer joy of seeing what excuse the CM's come up with to exclude me.

Comment: @Richard Can you nominate yourself again?

Comment: You'll win again.

Comment: @SS-3 - I haven't been told that I can't. That being said, there does exist a mechanism to exclude candidates that the CMs deem to be disruptive to the process. At least one candidate got zapped during my election.

Comment: It's also pretty interesting that they've decided to go ahead with the election while DVK and myself are chat-suspended, presenting a very large obstacle to canvassing for votes, should either of us throw our hats into the ring. I'm not saying it was deliberate, just interesting.

Comment: @DVK - You [score highly](http://data.stackexchange.com/scifi/query/edit/425089) as a potential moderator...

Comment: @Richard - that query seems to just have reputation and badge score only? Seems insufficient to judge moderation ability?

Comment: Let's give @JackBNimble another shot. He knows the site backwards and forwards, and this could be his last chance to declare that in fact, *everybody is dead to him.*

Comment: @DVK - It's the same measure used on the nomination page.

Comment: @MajorStackings - I'd like to think that the reason to give JBN another shot is that he's knowledgeable, helpful, not abrasive, and doesn't play favorites :)

Comment: @DVK Didn't I just say that? I meant to. Ahhh. I can see how easy it would be to mistake my ill worded but well intended comment that way. I blame it on JBN. He makes me feel funny.

Comment: Relevant - [Should Community Managers remain impartial during Moderator elections?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/273302/should-community-managers-remain-impartial-during-moderator-elections)

Comment: I could actually get behind @JackBNimble as a moderator here, I think the only reason he hasn't been elected is he goes a bit too heavy on the self-deprecation when he's nominated himself before.

Comment: @PearsonArtPhoto - I'd have no issues with him as a site-mod. I was anticipating he'd win last time around.

Comment: Am I understanding correctly that there are 11 candidates in the primary phase, and that the top 10 will progress to the election stage? In other words, are the primary votes solely to eliminate a single candidate?